# Pegar apenas o valor do retorno em um dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Uma query retorna isso?

```
var teste = _connection.Query(sQuery.ToString(), par).FirstOrDefault();
```

bem, dentro da **var teste** eu tenho isso:

```
UF = "MA"
```

mas eu quero apenas o **MA**.

Como eu faço para o dapper me retornar apenas o valor?

Comment: Está um pouco confuso, dê mais detalhes, qual é a query que ele está recebendo?

Comment: @ViníciusLima, como eu pego apenas o valor do dapper

Comment: O dapper deve te retornar um `dynamic` nesse caso. Basta fazer `var teste = _connection.Query(sQuery.ToString(), par).FirstOrDefault().UF;`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, coloque como resposta, que marco ela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesse caso, o dapper deve te retornar um objeto do tipo `dynamic`.

Basta fazer assim:

```
var teste = _connection.Query(sQuery.ToString(), par).FirstOrDefault().UF;
```

Como o tipo `dynamic` é uma implementação de [Late Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding), ele transfere a responsabilidade de conhecer o conteúdo do objeto para o programador em tempo de execução. Isso costuma ser uma *'faca de dois legumes'*. Ao mesmo tempo que dá esse tipo de comodidade, o código fica frágil para manutenções e uma pequena alteração na sua variável `sQuery`, por exemplo, pode causar problemas.

Nesse tipo de situação, você pode amenizar os efeitos negativos de utilizar o dynamic explicitando o que você espera como retorno já na sua consulta.

Supondo que sua consulta seja assim:

```
string sQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 UF FROM TabelaCidade WHERE codigo = @Codigo";
```

Você deve ser capaz de receber o mesmo resultado - e de uma maneira menos frágil - se fizer a `Query` desse jeito:

```
var teste = _connection.Query<string>(sQuery.ToString(), par).FirstOrDefault();
```

Assim, você conhecerá em tempo de compilação o tipo da variável `teste` e fica menos suscetível a erros futuros.

Answer (score 3):

Com o dapper você tem várias maneiras de fazer isto, segue abaixo exemplos:

```
//Aqui você está tipando o retorno em string e já pegando o primeiro resultado
var uf = _connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>(sQuery.ToString(), parm);

//Aqui você converte o retorno no seu model, e posteriormente poderá pegar seuModel.UF (onde uf é a propriedade)
var teste = _connection.Query<SeuModel>(sQuery.ToString(), par).FirstOrDefault();
var uf = teste.UF;
```

No site http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper você encontra mais informações.